# Sort by Double Value and not String Value

Tags: xcode, ios5

I'm currently pulling info from an sql DB where the 'cachedDist' column is set as a double.  However when I pull it into my app and create my array I turn it into an String and the sort will obviously be off, 18.15 will come before 2.15.  How do I fix that in my code so it will sort distance as a Double and not a String?

In Bar object.

```
NSString *cachedDist
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *cachedDist;
```

---

```
@synthesize cachedDist;
```

---

My while loop in the View Controller.

```
while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            Bar * bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
            bar.barName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            bar.barAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
            bar.barCity = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
            bar.barState = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];
            bar.barZip = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 5)];
            bar.barLat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 8)];
            bar.barLong = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 9)];

            if (currentLoc == nil) {
                NSLog(@"current location is nil %@", currentLoc);
            }else{

            CLLocation *barLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[bar.barLat doubleValue] longitude:[bar.barLong doubleValue]];
            bar.cachedDist = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[currentLoc distanceFromLocation: barLocation]/1000];

            [thebars addObject:bar];

            }
```

My sorting

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cachedDist"  ascending:YES];
sortedArray = [thebars sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

return sortedArray;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString has a method `doubleValue` to make this quite simple:

```
double cachedDistance = [cachedDistanceString doubleValue];
```

which you can use in a custom comparator for your sorting, or else make the property an NSNumber or double to make sorting that much easier. (I'm not sure how you are sorting...)

## edit:

I re-evaluated your code, and now it looks like we are going from a double to a string to a double... we can cut out the middle-man, so to speak.

In your @prototype section, change the @property:

```
// @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *cachedDist; // old way
@property(nonatomic) double cachedDist;
```

then assign it like this:

```
bar.cachedDistance = [currentLoc distanceFromLocation: barLocation]/1000;
```

and remove the lines which create a string from the distance (which is actually just a double).

Alternatively, if you want to be more object oriented, you can (should?) use NSNumber objects:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *cachedDist;
...
bar.cachedDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[currentLoc distanceFromLocation: barLocation]/1000];
```

Comment: Could I change `bar.cachedDist = distanceString:` to `double distanceDouble = [distanceString doubleValue];` and `bar.cachedDist = distanceDouble;`?

Comment: I tried this and when I try to assign `bar.cachedDist = distanceDouble;` I get an error 'Assigning to NSString from incompatible type double'

Comment: I edited to include suggestion to remove the NSString part altogether, with an option for either NSNumber or double for the property type.

Comment: Thats works, I've updated the code above.  Since I got rid of the NSString lines, but that is were I was formatting my number to only have 2 decimals.  How do I do that know?

Comment: It is recommended that you do any formatting (especially formatting which truncates accuracy) at a view stage of your code (i.e. wherever it is being "shown"). You should still store it with full accuracy.

Comment: Wherever you display it, keep in mind that you can use printf-style formatters in NSString's `stringWithFormat`, like this: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", bar.cachedDistance]`

Comment: By the way, when I change the my view `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ km", bar.cachedDist];` to `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f km", bar.cachedDist];` I get 0.00 km across the board now.  Any ideas where to look?

Comment: It would depend on how you stored cachedDistance. If it's an instance of NSNumber, you need to pass `doubleValue` to that method: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f km", [bar.cachedDist doubleValue]];`, and also you need to verify that it is non-nil. If it is nil, you may need to tweak the @property declaration to ensure it is being properly retained.

Comment: That worked, I didn't realize I had to use `doubleValue` because I thought `bar.cachedDist` already was a double at that point.  I will add that to my nil checks.